# Is there a way to identify the part number of a brick, just by using an image of it?

Tags: part-identification, bricks-and-pieces

I am trying to get my brother a custom made gift of an enemy he likes from a game. However, I don't know the names of the parts, and to make my problem harder I have never seen some of these parts. I need to order them online, however, without the name or part number, I am at a standstill. If anybody can shed some light on how to solve my situation, that would be very much appreciated. Here is the design for reference:

https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/6k9p4b/how_to_build_your_own_lego_guardian_botw/

Comment: Could you tell which specific image you need help with?

Comment: I am not specifically looking for the part #s of specific pieces, as there are to many that I don't know the names of. Rather, I am looking for a method of determining the part #s and names of the pieces. I edited my question to make my problem a bit clearer. Sorry for the miscommunication!

Comment: @UnorthodoxParadox Welcome to Bricks.SE! I've closed this question as a duplicate. Hopefully the answer on the other question helps you out. Certainly feel free ask additional questions if you get stuck on identifying specific parts. We're happy to help!